# How to create a Utils class for Vue.js that has access to Vuex this.$store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have a case where I want to fetch state from the Vuex `this.$store`. I researched and found out having a custom plugin installing an instance method might do the trick.

This is my plugin logic:

**index.ts**

```
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
  install: function (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$fetchVillager = function () {
      const players = this.$store.state.players
      const village = this.$store.state.villages.find(value => value.id === 0)
      const villagerIds = village.villagers

      const villagers = _.filter(players, function (player) {
        return villagerIds.includes(player.id)
      })
      if (!_.isNil(villagers)) {
        return villagers
      }
      return []
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I am using `this.$store.state.players` and therefore am accessing Vuex state. Using all this is pretty straightforward and does work as you can see here:

```
computed: {
    villagers: function () {
      return this.$fetchVillager()
    }
  }
```

However since I used `Vue.use(MyPlugin)` this function now is available everywhere. I kinda would like to restrict it to only those components I wanna use it in (there are three atm.).

So basically I'd love to have a simple `import VillageServices from '@/services/villageServices.ts` and just use the exposed functions from there. That surely does not work since with this approach there is no way to access Vuex `this.$store` since I am not bound to a Vue instance with that imported class.

Is there a way to achieve what I'd like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simply use a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

```
const villagers = {
    methods: {
        $fetchVillagers() {
            // use this.$store
        }
    }
};

const myComponent = new Vue({
    mixins: [villagers],
    computed: {
        villagers() {
            return this.$fetchVillagers();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I read about mixing being a bad pattern to use and should be avoided if possible - that's why I omitted them

Comment: I don't know where you read that but this is a very questionable opinion. Mixins do not exist by mistake. They are the exact tool you need for this.